# Referencing same value position in previous array within array of arrays / multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, loops, multidimensional-array

I am currently working with 2 functions, one returns an array of arrays (looking like this [[63,2],[74,3]]

At this time I have this:

```
let thermostatTempArray = [71, 72, 63, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 79, 78, 77]
    // index 2,3,4,5 = 63,74,75,76 === these indexes should return 
    // index 10,11,12 = 79,78,77 === these indexes should not return when successful
    let coolingCallsArray = [2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12,]

    function findValuesByIndex(indexGivenArray, valueGivenArray) {
      const matchedArray = []
      valueGivenArray.forEach(function (valueGiven,index) {
        const indexGiven = indexGivenArray[index]
        if (indexGiven !== undefined) {
          const matchingValue = valueGivenArray[indexGiven]
          matchedArray.push([matchingValue, indexGiven])
        }
      })
      return matchedArray
    }

    const coolingVals = findValuesByIndex(coolingCallsArray, thermostatTempArray)



    function findOverheatingTerminals(matchedArray) {
      overheatingTerminalsArray = []
      matchedArray.forEach(function(match,index) {
        const [matchingValue,matchedIndex] = match
          console.log(`Value: ${matchingValue} Index: ${matchedIndex}`)
          const prevMatchingVal = match[[0]]
          console.log(prevMatchingVal)
      } )
    }

    const overHeatingTerminals = findOverheatingTerminals(coolingVals)

    console.log(overHeatingTerminals)
```

What I am looking to do is compare the previous matching value (what might look like matchingValue[index-1] if it was in the same array) with the current value (i.e compare 74 with 63) - ONLY if the 2nd number in the array is successive (if it was [[63,2], [74,4] dont compare)I am just unsure how to get the variable right so I can even refer to the previous values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going up an array (to the matching arrays previous index) and destructuring it like this

```
function findOverheatingTerminals(matchedArray) {
  const overheatingTerminalsArray = []
  matchedArray.forEach(function (match, index) {
    const [matchingValue, matchedIndex] = match
    const prevMatchingArr = matchedArray[index - 1]
    if (prevMatchingArr !== undefined) {
      const [prevMatchingval, prevMatchindex] = prevMatchingArr
      if (matchingValue > prevMatchingval && matchedIndex === prevMatchindex + 1) {
        overheatingTerminalsArray.push(matchedIndex)
      }
    }
  })
  return overheatingTerminalsArray
}

exports.findOverheatingTerminals = findOverheatingTerminals
```